# how to alter modifications made in a file using vi editor?

Tags: data-recovery, vi

I have a query that how to alter modifications in a file -- that is, if I edited a file using vi and added some lines in that and saved it, but now I want my original file back without re-editing it.

Comment: if you want to exit vi without making any changes you need to use the :q command, if you saved your file then the original file is lost because vi doesnt make backups  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix/unix-vi-editor.htm

Comment: You can't do this unless you have version control setup before you edited the file.

Answer (score 1):

If you have not quit vim after writing your changes, you can execute below vim command to undo all changes made since opening a file.

> :u1|u

The command above first runs the command :undo 1, then :undo. The former command jumps to after the first change, the latter one undoes that first change

Answer (score 0):

The Vi that you are using is likely Vim (since you are on a Linux system).

Vim has a `backup` option that has the effect of creating a backup of the existing file on disk before saving the current buffer.  The backup will have the same name as the original file, but with a `~` appended at the end of its filename.

To enable this feature, add

```
set backup
```

to your `~/.vimrc` file.

To change the backup extension, set `backupext` to the wanted suffix:

```
set backup
set backupext=.bak
```

You may also change *where* backups are stored by setting `backupdir` to a directory name.  The default value of `backupdir` is `.,~/tmp,~/`.  This means that Vim first tries to save the backup in the current directory (`.`), but if that fails (for whatever reason) it tries again with `~/tmp`, and then again with `~/`.

See also `:help backup` from within Vim.

Vi does not have this feature.